# Unable to find element within span tag

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm Trying to webscrape data off this site: https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment
For example I'd like to know how much % of the clients are long on EUR/USD but I'm unable to get the text within the span tag.

I'm trying to get the 61%

```
<span class="bullish-color jsdfx-sentiment-long" style="font-size: 15px;">61%</span>
```

'''

```
import bs4, requests

dailyfxSite = 'https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment'

res = requests.get(dailyfxSite)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

span = soup.find("span", class_="bullish-color jsdfx-sentiment-long")
print(span)
```

'''

I get this as return:

```
<span class="bullish-color jsdfx-sentiment-long" style="font-size:15px;"> </span>
```

'''

everything except the 61% I need

Comment: Greetings! Maybe that value is inserted via javascript? If so, that span _is_ empty until some script executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with how the data are created on the website. It looks like the website is loading the data using JavaScript (i.e., the span element is created dynamically using JavaScript). `requests` don't work with elements that are dynamically created by JavaScript.

I recommend using selenium to open the website:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://www.dailyfx.com/sentiment"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
browser.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, features="html.parser")
a = soup.find("span", {"class": "bullish-color"})
print(a.text)
```

Output:

```
61%
```

You might need a different way to create the `browser` (the one I am showing above works on macOS given some custom configuration). Have a look around on how to create a browser using selenium on your platform.

Answer (score 0):

Try Css Selector to get that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<span class="bullish-color jsdfx-sentiment-long" style="font-size: 15px;">61%</span>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one("span.bullish-color.jsdfx-sentiment-long").text)
```

Output :

```
61%
```